# Grouping a sorted table into 5% segments for counts, sums, avgs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking at a table of customers for an ecommerce website and trying to group the customers by revenue into 5% segments and run a few COUNTs, SUMs, and AVGs across each segment.

I've started by ORDER-ing the table by revenue and adding a ROW_NUMBER() function, but I'm struggling with how to turn that into a "percentile" column I can GROUP the rows with.

It would have to be something where you divide the ROW_NUMBER() by the COUNT of customers, but that's what I need help with.

The basic customers table looks something like this:

```
customer_id  | num_orders | revenue 
-------------------------------------
      1      |     1      |   50.0
      2      |     3      |   60.0
      3      |     7      |   80.0
      4      |     2      |   90.0
      5      |     9      |   110.0
      6      |     1      |   160.0
      7      |     2      |   80.0
      8      |     1      |   10.0
      9      |     3      |   120.0
      10     |     2      |   120.0
...
      515    |     2      |   70.0
      516    |     3      |   30.0
      517    |     6      |   20.0
      518    |     1      |   10.0
      519    |     8      |   120.0
```

And I'm looking for something like this:

```
  percentile   | num_customers | num_single_orders | avg_revenue 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
      5%       |       26      |          1        |   2050.0
      10%      |       26      |          2        |   260.0
      15%      |       26      |          4        |   180.0
      20%      |       26      |          5        |   90.0
      25%      |       26      |          9        |   70.0
      30%      |       26      |          11       |   60.0
      35%      |       26      |          15       |   50.0
      40%      |       26      |          16       |   40.0
      45%      |       26      |          17       |   35.0
      50%      |       26      |          18       |   30.0
...
      100%     |       26      |          25       |   1.0
```

My code would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(customer_id),
SUM(CASE WHEN num_orders = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) num_single_orders,
AVG(revenue),
ROUND(row/COUNT(customer_id),0) percentile

FROM (
  SELECT
  customer_id,
  num_orders,
  revenue,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY revenue DESC) AS row

  FROM customers
)
GROUP BY percentile
```

But I don't know how to divide "row" by a COUNT without GROUPing by row, because that doesn't work either. I'm sure there's a simple solution I haven't figured out yet.

Thank you for anyone that can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ntile()`, but your method also works.  Put `count()` in the subquery:

```
SELECT FLOOR(seqnum * 100 / cnt) as tile,
       COUNT(customer_id),
       COUNTIF( num_orders = 1 )   as num_single_orders,
       AVG(revenue),
ROUND(row/COUNT(customer_id),0) percentile

FROM (SELECT c.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY revenue DESC) - 1 AS seqnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
      FROM customers c
     ) c
GROUP BY tile
ORDER BY tile;
```

This produces 100 groups.  If you want 20, then use `20` instead of `100`.

Note that the groups will be as close in size as possible, so tied values can be in different tiles.  If you want to keep such values together, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I tried out this and NTILE and NTILE is actually really simple--I used that in the subquery and then GROUPed based on that. What a great function. Thanks!

Comment: @LeeLK . . . I prefer doing the calculation myself, because then I don't have to remember how ties are handled.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Assuming you want 20 segments ... (otherwise you should change 20 to whatever you want in two places below)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT (100 * segment / 20) AS percentile, * 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    CEIL(row_num * 20 / cnt) AS segment,
    COUNT(customer_id) num_customers,
    COUNTIF(num_orders = 1) AS num_single_orders,
    ROUND(AVG(revenue), 2) avg_revenue
  FROM (
    SELECT   
      customer_id,
      num_orders,
      revenue, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY revenue DESC) AS row_num,
      COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt
    FROM `project.dataset.customers`
  )
  GROUP BY segment
)
-- ORDER BY segment
```

output will looks like

```
Row percentile  segment num_customers   num_single_orders   avg_revenue  
1   5.0         1.0     1               1                   160.0    
2   10.0        2.0     2               0                   120.0    
3   15.0        3.0     2               0                   120.0    
4   20.0        4.0     1               0                   120.0    
. . . 
18  90.0        18.0    2               1                   55.0     
19  95.0        19.0    2               0                   25.0     
20  100.0       20.0    2               2                   10.0
```

Comment: @leelk - did you have chance to try my answer?

Comment: I already built out my query with Gordon's idea above but thanks for the alternative! I think your method would have been what I would have ended up with if I had just tried to figure it out on my own--using another subquery to identify the 'segments'. Thanks!

Comment: ...interesting response!

Comment: :o) that's exactly what I thought when read your previous comment - then I laughed a minute - and then shared my reaction via comment :o)

Comment: that reminded me an old Russian proverb "Если бы у бабушки были яйца, то она была бы дедушкой" - which if to translate in English - will be "If only Grandma had balls, she would have been Grandpa". Sorry for jokes - I am a proud Grandpa - so thought I would qualify for some jokes